# Get last row in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

What I am trying to do it with below code, getting all keywords with their positions via LEFT JOIN, it works fine but it shows the first position of each keyword, but I want to show the last position that recorded (by date).

```
SELECT keyword.id, keyword.title, keyword.date, rank.position FROM keyword 
LEFT JOIN rank
ON rank.wordid = keyword.id
GROUP BY keyword.id
ORDER BY keyword.date DESC
```

How can I do this? Should I use subquery or what? Is there any way to do this without a subquery?

**[SAMPLE DATA](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2f7254/1/0)**

**What I want:**

Get 17 instead of 13, I mean last record of position.

Comment: `SELECT keyword.id, keyword.title, keyword.date, rank.position ... GROUP BY keyword.id` is a invalid query which will case invalid results.. Priove example data with expected ouput place it on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or https://www.db-fiddle.com/.. And also give us the MySQL version with `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: @RaymondNijland But I got my results, why is invalid?

Comment: This explains why http://www.riptutorial.com/mysql/example/26486/using-and-misusing-group-by

Comment: @tourtravel . . . Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `group by` for this!  You want to filter, so use a `where` clause.  In this case, using a correlated subquery works well:

```
SELECT k.id, k.title, k.date, r.position
FROM keyword k LEFT JOIN
     rank r
     ON r.wordid = k.id AND
        r.date = (SELECT MAX(r2.date)
                  FROM rank r2
                  WHERE r2.wordid = k.id
                 )
ORDER BY k.date DESC
```

Comment: I got error `Trying to get property of non-object` with your code

Comment: @tourtravel . . . Your question suggests that the rankings have a date field "want to show the last position that recorded (by date)".  You may need to use the correct column name.

Comment: "Trying to get property of non-object" is a PHP error not a MySQL error @tourtravel

Comment: @RaymondNijland Did you see my code in question? I copied this answer to `$sql = "..."` so what? I run my code and it return a php error with this code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff both has `date` field.. I don't understand you.

Comment: @tourtravel . . . The `rank.position` in the `SELECT` would have caused a query error.  You should be checking for errors whenever you run queries.  In any case, that's now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
SELECT keyword.id, keyword.title, keyword.date, rankNew.position FROM keyword LEFT JOIN (
SELECT rank.wordid, rank.position FROM rank ORDER BY rank.id DESC LIMIT 0, 1) AS rankNew ON (rankNew.wordid = keyword.id);
```

You can get more reference from [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)